# Curl ssl error 35 on mac but not on linux

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I tried to curl something over sll with certs authentication:

```
curl -E ~/mycert.pem "https://<stuff>"
```

On my mac I am getting the following error:

```
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to <stuff>:-9824
```

Exactly the same command with exactly the same cert file on my linux vm is working fine.
OpenSSL version on mac:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2c 12 Jun 2015
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: clang -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -fno-common -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB_SHARED -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/etc/openssl"
```

OpenSSL version on Linux VM:

```
OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
built on: Mon Jan 12 03:40:30 EST 2015
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(ptr2) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -I/usr/kerberos/include -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DOPENSSL_USE_NEW_FUNCTIONS -fno-strict-aliasing -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  dynamic
```

I just updated my OpenSSL on mac to the latest. Went through few topics on the internet but none seems to work... Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).